# using jQuery to select elements until an element has a particular class, apply wrapALL to each set

Tags: jquery, select, flexbox, wrapall

My html is as below

```
<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="A">
<input name="name2" value="A">
<input class="endFlex" name="name3" value="A">

<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="B">
<input name="name4 value="B">
<input name="name5" value="B">
<input name="name6" value="B">
<input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="B">

<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="C">
<input name="name7" value="C">
<input name="name8" value="C">
<input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="C">
```

I want to use jQuery to select groups of elements. The group begins at class beginFlex and ends at endFlex. Then I wan to apply wrapAll() so that I get the code as below:

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="A">
    <input name="name2" value="A">
    <input class="endFlex" name="name3" value="A">
</div>

<div style="display:flex">
    <input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="B">
    <input name="name4 value="B">
    <input name="name5" value="B">
    <input name="name6" value="B">
    <input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="B">
</div>

<div style="display:flex">
    <input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="C">
    <input name="name7" value="C">
    <input name="name8" value="C">
    <input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="C">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can select all the `.beginFlex` elements and loop through them. From there you can use `nextUntil()` to select all the inputs until the next `.beginFlex` and wrap them in a div. Try this:

```js
$('input.beginFlex').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.beginFlex').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="flex" />');
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  
  /* to show it working */
  border: 1px solid #C00; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="A">
<input name="name2" value="A">
<input class="endFlex" name="name3" value="A">

<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="B">
<input name="name4" value="B">
<input name="name5" value="B">
<input name="name6" value="B">
<input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="B">

<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="C">
<input name="name7" value="C">
<input name="name8" value="C">
<input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="C">
```

Comment: This works. My real problem was slightly complicated. But with this I could resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `netUntill` to select all elements, use `add` to select the first and last elements

Try the following

```js
  $('.beginFlex').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.endFlex').add($(this)).add($(this).nextAll('.endFlex')[0]).wrapAll('<div style="display:flex">');
  });
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="A">
<input name="name2" value="A">
<input class="endFlex" name="name3" value="A">

<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="B">
<input name="name4" value="B">
<input name="name5" value="B">
<input name="name6" value="B">
<input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="B">

<input class="beginFlex" name="name1" value="C">
<input name="name7" value="C">
<input name="name8" value="C">
<input class="endFlex" name="name1" value="C">
```

Comment: `nextUntil()` needs `andSelf()` in this case, and `nextUntil('.endFlex')` will miss the last element in each set